# Create a reusable timer in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I have a countdown timer and I use it in a few places.

The code is something like :

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        remainingTime: null
    };

}

componentWillMount(){
    const list = this.props.list;
    const t = Date.parse(list.expires) - Date.parse(new Date());
    if(t > 0){
        this.setState({remainingTime: t});
    }else{
        this.setState({remainingTime: 0});
    }

}

componentDidMount(){
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}

tick(){
    if(this.state.remainingTime > 0) {
        this.setState({remainingTime: this.state.remainingTime - 1000});
        if (this.state.remainingTime <= 0) {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
    }else{
        this.setState({remainingTime: 0});
    }
}
```

Where `list.expires` is something like : `"Tue November 29 2016 23:59:59 GMT+0200"`.

Like I said, I use this timer in a few components and in every component I have this same code.

How can I put this code somewhere else, in one place, and then reuse it in all other components?

Answer (score 0):

I think You wanna export the component and to do this place this at the bottom of the component

"export default ClassNameHere"

.To import it where You need, use

" import Alias from './path/ClassNameHere'"

Big Edit (link to the docs):

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html